GSAP ScrollTrigger Markers Moving with Scroll Instead of Staying Fixed - React Vite
I'm working on a project using GSAP's ScrollTrigger in react, but I have an issue where the markers (start, end, etc.) move with the scroll instead of staying fixed on the page. Both the scollers and the triggers are scrolling on page scroll which isn't letting the triggers to trigger animations, i am learning so please guide me, any help would be appreciated, thank you!
Here is the Landing Page component
import React, { useEffect, useRef,useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import LocomotiveScroll from "locomotive-scroll";
import "locomotive-scroll/dist/locomotive-scroll.css";
import Header from "../Components/Header.comp";
import Hero from "../Components/Hero.comp";
import About from "../Components/About.comp";
import Services from "../Components/Services.comp";
import Stats from "../Components/Stats.comp";
import Projects from "../Components/Projects.comp";
import WhyUs from "../Components/WhyUs.comp";
import Feedback from "../Components/Feedback.comp";
import Contact from "../Components/Contact.comp";
import Footer from "../Components/Footer.comp";
import { createContext } from "react";
import { useGSAP } from "@gsap/react";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
import gsap from "gsap";
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
export const TLContext = createContext();
function LandingPage() {
  const tl = gsap.timeline();

  const scrollRef = useRef();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const locoScroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
      el: scrollRef.current,
      smooth: true,
  
      smartphone: {
        smooth: true,
      },
      tablet: {
        smooth: true,
      },
    });
  
    ScrollTrigger.scrollerProxy(scrollRef.current, {
      scrollTop(value) {
        return arguments.length
          ? locoScroll.scrollTo(value, 0, 0)
          : locoScroll.scroll.instance.scroll.y;
      },
      getBoundingClientRect() {
        return {
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: window.innerWidth,
          height: window.innerHeight,
        };
      },
      pinType: scrollRef.current.style.transform ? "transform" : "fixed",
    });
  
    locoScroll.on("scroll", ScrollTrigger.update);
  
    ScrollTrigger.addEventListener("refresh", () => locoScroll.update());
    ScrollTrigger.refresh();
  
    // Ensure Locomotive updates on resize
    const handleResize = () => {
      locoScroll.update();
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  
    return () => {
      locoScroll.destroy();
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <TLContext.Provider value={tl}>
      <div
        ref={scrollRef}
        data-scroll-container
        className= "flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full bg-black page"
      >
        <Header />
        <Hero />
        <About />
        <Services />
        <Stats />
        <Projects />
        <WhyUs />
        <Feedback />
        <Contact />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </TLContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default LandingPage;


And here is the Hero component
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useGSAP } from "@gsap/react";
import gsap from "gsap";
import SplitText from "./Utils/SplitText";
import { TLContext } from "../Pages/Landing.page";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
function Hero() {
  const tl = useContext(TLContext);
  if (tl) {
    console.log("a");
  }
  const getInTouch = useRef();
  useGSAP(() => {
 
    gsap.to(".image_hero_girl", {
      scrollTrigger: {
        markers: true,
        trigger: ".image_hero_girl",
        scroller: ".Hero",
        start: "top 10%",
        end: "top 0%",
        scrub: 5,
      },
      y: 80,
      duration: 1,
    });
    if (tl) {
      tl.from(".shadow ", {
        opacity: 0,
        delay: 0.5,
        x: 400,
        duration: 1,
        stagger: 1,
      });

      tl.from(".bringUp", {
        x: 100,
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 1,
        stagger: 0.1,

        ease: "bounce.out",
      });
    }
  }, []);
  const getInTouchEnter = () => {
    gsap.to(getInTouch.current, {
      duration: 0.5,
      delay: 0.1,
      x: 20,
    });
  };
  const getInTouchLeave = () => {
    gsap.to(getInTouch.current, {
      duration: 0.5,
      delay: 0.1,
      x: 0,
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <section className="relative Hero flex justify-center bg-black  w-full  z-[100]   h-[85vh] ">
        <div className=" bg-gradient-to-l shadow from-[#6d96fc3b] right-0 to-[#6d96fc00]  absolute top-0 z-[200] w-[60%] h-full object-cover"></div>
        <div className="  w-[90%] h-full flex justify-center items-center ">
          <div className="flex h-full  flex-col items-start justify-center w-[45%] gap-5">
            <p className="text-[#6D95FC] text-[21px] uppercase welcome bringUp">
              Welcome to creatic
            </p>
            <h2 className=" font-bold  text-white text-[50px] bringUp">
              WE ARE <span className="text-[#6D95FC]">CREATIVE</span>
              <br /> DESIGN AGENCY
            </h2>
            <hr className="border-[#6D95FC] border-2 rounded-lg w-1/3 bringUp" />
            <p className="text-white text-[18px] font-light bringUp">
              Lorem ipsumNeque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor
              sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit Neque porro elit Neque porro
              quis ipsum
            </p>
            <button
              ref={getInTouch}
              onMouseLeave={getInTouchLeave}
              onMouseEnter={getInTouchEnter}
              className=" mt-4 p-5 py-2 hover:bg-[#6D95FC] bringUp  uppercase text-white border-4 getInTouch  border-[#6D95FC]"
            >
              Get in touch
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-end justify-start  w-[55%] h-full">
            <img
              src="./Hero/women_hero.png"
              className="  image_hero_girl opacity max-w-[100%] w-full  "
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default Hero;

I tried implementing the GSAP ScrollTrigger with markers to debug my animations. I also removed Locomotive Scroll to ensure no conflicts were causing the issue. I expected the markers to stay fixed in the viewport, helping me visualize the start and end points of my animation.
However, even without Locomotive Scroll, the markers still move with the page's content, making it hard to debug. I called ScrollTrigger.refresh() to ensure the markers were updated correctly, but the problem persists.

It was fixed by placing the reference(scrollRef) for the main div on which the locomotive was applied in the scroller.
gsap.to(".image_hero_girl, .hero_content", {
scrollTrigger: {
markers: false,
trigger: ".image_hero_girl",
scroller: scrollRef.current,
start: "top 10%",
end: "10% 20%",
scrub: 5,
},
y: 30,
duration: 0.5,
ease: "power2.in",
});
